# d undefined for d3.tip() tooltip with dc.leafletChoroplethChart

Tags: dc.js

I'm trying to use `d3.tip()` to create a popup window when mousing over a dc.leafletChoroplethChart. I'm really close, the problem is that `d` is undefined in the `html` call of the tooltip:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
.attr("class", "d3-tip")
.html(function(d) {
    console.log("d:", d) //returns undefined
    return d;
});
```

I put the above code just before the `d3.json("geojson/file.json", function(states)` loop.

Then in the loop:

```
drawChoropleth(csv,states);

choroChart = dc.leafletChoroplethChart("#choro-map .map")                
              .dimension(regionDimension)
              .group(avgRegionGroup)
              .valueAccessor(function(p) {
                    return p.value.average;
               })
              .width(600)
              .height(400)
              .center([47.00, 2.00])
              .zoom(5)
              .geojson(geojson)              
              .colors(["#E2F2FF", "#C4E4FF", "#9ED2FF", "#81C5FF", "#6BBAFF", "#51AEFF", "#36A2FF", "#1E96FF", "#0089FF", "#0061B5"])
              .colorDomain(function() {
                return [dc.utils.groupMin(this.group(), this.valueAccessor()),
                 dc.utils.groupMax(this.group(), this.valueAccessor())];
              })
              .colorAccessor(function(d,i) {
                return d.value.average;
              })
              .featureKeyAccessor(function(feature) {                   
                return feature.properties.name;
              });

choroChart.renderlet(function(chart) {
    chart.selectAll("path").call(tip);
    chart.selectAll("path").on("mouseover", tip.show);
});
```

When mousing over, a popup window appears but it doesn't contain anything because `d` is undefined. Any idea how to get at the name of the regions?

Thank you!

Comment: interesting question. dc.leaflet.js does not actually use d3 for its drawing; it uses leaflet's built-in graphics. but it might be possible to modify its `_doRedraw` to bind the data once leaflet does the drawing.

Comment: Opened an issue on this community fork of dc.leaflet.js: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.leaflet.js/issues/1

Comment: @Gordon I didn't figure out how to use d3.tip to make a popup window, but I did suceed in using leaflet. I added a `mouseover` event in the `processFeatures` function in `dc.leaflet.js`: I added this line `layer.on('mouseover', function (e) { this.openPopup();  });` after `layer.bindPopup(_chart.popup()(v.d,feature));`

Comment: Interesting, that's a good workaround. So you're still using d3.tip but opening it manually?

Comment: No, I'm not using d3.tip at all. I defined a Leaflet mouseover event handler and called the Leaflet `openPopup` function (defined in leaflet.js). (Aside: it's not clear to me how to modify the position of these popup windows).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to using d3-tip with leaflet is binding the data to the g elements after they're inserted a simple way to achieve this is:

```
_chart.map().on('layeradd', function(d){
    if (!d.layer.feature) return;
    d3.select(d.layer._container).datum(d.layer.feature);
});
```